# python compare two texts files en print the output to another file

Tags: python, list

**file1.txt**

```
neighbor 192.168.3.1 remote-as 200
neighbor 192.168.4.1 remote-as 300
neighbor 192.168.15.1 remote-as 400
neighbor 192.168.16.1 remote-as 500
neighbor 20.249.208.165 remote-as 200
neighbor 80.249.208.165 remote-as 100
neighbor 192.168.5.1 remote-as 400
```

**file2.txt**

```
neighbor 26.24.1.165 remote-as 200
neighbor 90.239.208.165 remote-as 100
neighbor 192.168.3.1 remote-as 200
neighbor 192.168.4.1 remote-as 300
neighbor 192.168.5.1 remote-as 400
neighbor 192.168.6.1 remote-as 500
neighbor 192.168.15.1 remote-as 400
neighbor 192.168.16.1 remote-as 500
```

i have these two files!!!!
i want to compare each line of file1.txt with all lines from file2.txt and print the lines which doenst match.

i have tried a lot of mothods, sometime having problem to use variables outside of for loops! can anyone help me !!! Thanks

Comment: Show more effort on your own (and code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

```
file_one = open('file1.txt', 'r')
file_two = open('file2.txt', 'r')

content = file_one.readlines()
content_2 = file_two.readlines()

non_match = []

for line in content:
    if line not in content_2:
        non_match.append(line)

print(('\n').join(non_match))

file_one.close()
file_two.close()
```

~

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~$ python3.7 search.py 
> neighbor 20.249.208.165 remote-as 200
>
> neighbor 80.249.208.165 remote-as 100
> ```